# How to convert unicode \:0936\:093e\:092e to Devanagari script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have created a Twitter bot based on Google Apps Script and wolfram|alpha. The bot answers questions the way wolfram|alpha does.

I need to translate a string from English to Devanagari. 
I get result as `\:0936\:093e\:092e` which should be converted to "शाम"

Here is a link for more info - https://codepoints.net/U+0936?lang=en

I want to know how I can achieve this using Google Apps Script (JavaScript)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values in `\:0936\:093e\:092e` are UTF-16 character codes, but are not expressed in a way that will render the characters you need. If they were, you could use the answer from [Expressing UTF-16 unicode characters in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126384/expressing-utf-16-unicode-characters-in-javascript) directly.

#### Demo

This script extracts the hexadecimal numbers from the given string, then uses the `getUnicodeCharacter()` function from the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126384/expressing-utf-16-unicode-characters-in-javascript) to convert each number, or *codepoint*, into its Unicode character.

```js
function utf16demo() {
  var str = "\:0936\:093e\:092e";
  var charCodes = str.replace(/\:/,'').split('\:').map(function(st){return parseInt(st,16);});
  var newStr = '';
  for (var ch=0; ch < charCodes.length; ch++) {
    newStr += getUnicodeCharacter(charCodes[ch])
  }
  Logger.log(newStr);
}
```

#### Log

```
[15-11-03 23:04:16:096 EST] शाम
```